# android intent chooser slow to appear

Tags: android, android-intent, runnable

When users have a lot of possible apps that can accept a certain kind of intent, the intentchooser takes a while to load, a noticeable amount of time at least

Yet this waiting happens after I launch intent, is there any way I can put up some kind of loading indicator or intermediary visual element to make time less noticeable to the user?

Comment: It shouldn't take long at all to query the system for available intents.  Are you sure you're not doing any processing before launching the intent?  Code example maybe?

Comment: @ashishduh I can confirm that it really is slow. Even with the most basic intent, all my apps and phones have taken long to load the list.

Comment: @CQM have you found a way to solve this?

Comment: I tried pre-resolving the chooser activity before calling startActivity (in order to show a progress bar during activity resolution if that was the holdup), but that didn't help. It appears the work is being done after the chooser activity is started.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my manifest for the activity that uses the chooser:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

It seems to load faster now.

Comment: This changes the chooser values completely.